# (UE4) Transform Bone Node of Animated Blueprint in C++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

i got an animated Blueprint which moves the bones of a skeleton with [this method](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Animation/NodeReference/SkeletalControls/TransformBone/index.html). Now i want to translate my Blueprint in C++ Code but i do not know how i can access this method in my code. Can you guys maybe tell me how to use them in my Code? I did not find any solution for this and now i hope i can get some help here.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: First find the "Transform (Modify) Bone" string in your solution and you'll find `UAnimGraphNode_ModifyBone`. Check the codes of this class and its base class and see what you need.